How to grant permission to Deactivate and Active ApexTrigger via API
How do I use the REST API to update an Apex Trigger?
vctqs1@Thus-MacBook-Pro erp-salesforce % curl -s -X PATCH -H 'Authorization: Bearer <Token>' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --location https://baybridge-stream-8270.scratch.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexTrigger/01qH40000009eiJIAQ --data '{ "Status": "Active" }'


[{"message":"insufficient access rights on cross-reference id","errorCode":"INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY","fields":[]}]%     

and getting error INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY but im using System Admin, Do everyone know which permission we should grant?
Also getting same error if using sf data update
vctqs1@Thus-MacBook-Pro erp-salesforce % sf data update record --use-tooling-api --target-org staging_manabie --sobject ApexTrigger --record-id  01qJ2000000k9sYIAQ  --values "Status='Inactive'"

